# change path name from each rows of the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I have a CSV file with 6 columns and the first column is the file name with the directory(`/imgs/train/uav0000072_05448_v/0000001.jpg`). now I want to add the full directory path with every row of this column(i.e `/home/Documnet/project/images/imgs/train/uav0000072_05448_v/0000001.jpg`). I am now confused about how to do that? [CSV file with the column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MccOU.png)

First I have separated all the columns to simplify things. But after that, I am confused about how to do the rest?

```
df = pd.read_csv('~/Documents/project/csv/images.csv', usecols= [0], header = 0)
```

I think it's possible through pandas but I am now sure how? Any help would be appreciated. Maybe a link as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas `apply` function.
Let's say column name with paths is `col` then

```
df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda s: '/home/Document/project/images'+s)
```

Comment: ok. I will try that. Thanks. But from the CSV file if I don't separate the columns, is it also possible to use apply function?

Comment: Yes apply function runs on a column of pandas dataframe. Read whole of csv in a pandas dataframe and then run apply function on appropriate column that you want to transform.

Comment: this apply function is adding the extra path in every row but then other columns are not there in the CSV file.  `df = pd.read_csv('/home/ps/Documents/project/csv/images.csv')
#print(df)
#print(df.iloc[:,0])                                                                                                                       
col = df.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda s: '/home/ps/Documents/project/images'+s)
print(col)
col.to_csv('/home/ps/Documents/project/smart2rail/csv/out.csv')`

Comment: upvote the answer..if it solved your problem!